# Obtengo el error: "Cannot read property 'slug' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
    
const data = {
    image: "https://ucarecdn.com/f8cf81eb-3bab-4bba-9431-668884eab174/-/resize/300x/",
    cardTitle: "Bob Dylan",
    cardDescription:
        "Bob Dylan (born Robert Allen Zimmerman, May 24, 1941) is an American singer-songwriter, author, and artist who has been an influential figure in popular music and culture for more than five decades.",
    button: {
        url: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bob_Dylan",
        label: "Go to wikipedia"
    }
};
    
function content() {
    return (
        <div className="card m-5">
            <img className="card-img-top" src={data.image} alt="Card image cap" />

            <div className="card-body">
                <h5 className="card-title">{data.cardTitle} </h5>
                <p className="card-text"> {data.cardDescription} </p>

                <a href={data.url} className="btn btn-primary">
                    {data.label}
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
    
ReactDOM.render(content, document.querySelector("#myDiv"));
```

Comment: Pareciera que falta mas informacion para determinar donde esta el error, puedes incluir el codigo del componente donde se usa `.slug`?

Comment: ```
>esto fue lo que hice
    function content() {
     return (
      <div className="card m-5">
       <img className="card-img-top" src={data.image} alt="Card image cap" />

Comment: <div className="card-body">
        <h5 className="card-title">{data.cardTitle} </h5>
        <p className="card-text"> {data.cardDescription} </p>
        <a href={data.url} className="btn btn-primary">
         {data.label}
        </a>
       </div>
      </div>
     );
    }
    
    ReactDOM.render(content, document.querySelector("#myDiv"));''

```

Comment: No me dej colocar el codigo comppleto

Comment: @BeatrizHernandez Pon el código en tu pregunta, recuerda que puedes editarla ;)

Comment: Hola Beatriz puedes editar tu pregunta y agregar el codigo del componente para poder leerlo mejor, dandole formato de codigo.

Comment: También hace falta que expliques que está haciendo y des un contexto claro.

Comment: Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.